# Mismatch in record pattern and type on database record in F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

How do I fix the following errors?

***This expression was expected to have type 'string * Nullable * Nullable' but here has type 'VisitType'***  (Error occurs on "|AppointmentOnly(q.lastname, q.posting_time)).

and

***Field 'appointmentTime' is not static*** (Error occurs on FsVisit.appointmentTime = q.appointment_time;).

(These errors occur in my attempt to download records from a PostgreSQL database via WCF into F# client).

```
type VisitType = 
| AppointmentOnly of name: string * postedTime: DateTime
| WalkIn of name: string * serviceTime: DateTime
| Kept of name: string * postedTime: DateTime * serviceTime: DateTime
| Open


type FsVisit =
     { appointmentTime: Nullable<DateTime>
       visitType: VisitType }
with
    member this.Name =
       match this.visitType with
       | AppointmentOnly(name=name) | WalkIn(name=name) | Kept(name=name) -> Some name
       | Open -> None

let TestGetScheduleAsync (tableDate : DateTime) =
    async {
        let! data = context.GetOfficeScheduleAsync(tableDate) |> Async.AwaitTask
        return data |> Seq.map ( fun q -> 
            FsVisit.appointmentTime = q.appointment_time;
                      match (q.lastname, q.posting_time, q.service_time) with
                      | AppointmentOnly(q.lastname, q.posting_time) -> AppointmentOnly({name = q.lastname; postedTime = q.posting_time})
                      | WalkIn(q.lastname, q.service_time) -> WalkIn({name =q.lastname; serviceTime = q.service_time})
                      | Kept(q.lastname, q.posting_time, q.service_time) -> Kept({name=q.lastname; postedTime = q.posting_time, serviceTime = q.service_time})
                      | Open -> None

        )}
         |> Async.StartAsTask
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You're trying to match the tuple `(q.lastname, q.posting_time, q.service_time)` you're creating with constructors for the type `VisitType`. What are you trying to do with that `match` expression?

Comment: @Lee This code is a distilled form of a C# class I was using in which I eventually needed subclassing and if/then statement to give a different behavior  for whether the visit was a "WalkIn" or Apppointment Only (etc.). My thinking is if I could separate out the different Visit types immediately I could eventually junk all the if/thens when assigning behaviors.  I could be very wrong, but this has been a good learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuple of `lastname`, `posting_time`, and `service_time` is not a value of `VisitType` type. So you cannot match it with `VisitType` discriminated union cases. I assume that `posting_time` and `service_time` are `Nullable<DateTime>` values (same as `appointment_time`) So you should match tuple with tuple and create `VisitType` case depending on `posting_time` and `service_time` value (`Some` or `None`). I also would remove name from matching

```
match (Option.ofNullable q.posting_time, Option.ofNullable q.service_time) with
| (Some postedTime, None) -> AppointmentOnly(q.lastname, postedTime)
| (None, Some serviceTime) -> WalkIn(q.lastname, serviceTime)
| (Some postedTime, Some serviceTime) -> Kept(q.lastname, postedTime, serviceTime)
| _ -> Open
```

You can adjust this code if you want `VisitType option` by returning `None` for `Open` case and `Some` for other cases.

---

Note that your code can be compilable as well if you'll add [active patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/active-patterns) which will create so-called named partitions for your input data (tuple):

```
let (|AppointmentOnly|WalkIn|Kept|Open|)
    (name: string, postedTime: Nullable<DateTime>, serviceTime: Nullable<DateTime>) =
        match (Option.ofNullable postedTime, Option.ofNullable serviceTime) with
        | (Some postedTime, None) -> AppointmentOnly(name, postedTime)
        | (None, Some serviceTime) -> WalkIn(name, serviceTime)
        | (Some postedTime, Some serviceTime) -> Kept(name, postedTime, serviceTime)
        | (None, None) -> Open
```

Keep in mind that `AppointementOnly`, `WalkIn`, `Kept`, `Open` returned here is not a discriminated union cases - it's an active pattern records. Now you can use this active pattern to divide your input data into partitions and create corresponding `VisitType` cases:

```
match (q.lastname, q.posting_time, q.service_time) with
| AppointmentOnly(name, postedTime) -> AppointmentOnly(name, postedTime)
| WalkIn(name, serviceTime) -> WalkIn(name, serviceTime)
| Kept(name, postedTime, serviceTime) -> Kept(name, postedTime, serviceTime)
| Open -> Open
```

Again, here we are matching on the active pattern and then creating a discriminated union:

```
| AppointmentOnly(name, postedTime) -> AppointmentOnly(name, postedTime)
              ^                                    ^
     ACTIVE PATTERN IDENTIFIER                  UNION CASE
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for explaining this to a newbie. F# seems to have a much steeper learning curve then the blogs and tutorials seem to indicate. Your explanation helped clarify much confusion on my part.